# Theming the GRUB2

Tags: grub2, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get some nice eye candy themes for Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub)

Can I theme the GRUB2, and does anyone have any advice on doing this? Thanks in advance.