# Editing GRUB2 listing and background-image?

Tags: grub2, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get some nice eye candy themes for Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub)

Im using ubuntu 12.10.Is that possible to list only ubuntu loader and windows7 loader in GRUB2?
With a Image background or something theme that will not damage boot?

Can you provide some tutorials.
Or something tool/application to edit grub easily with matching dynamic image input

Answer (score 0):

You could try Grub Customizer.

> Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the GRUB2/BURG
>   settings and menu entries

Features:

- move, remove or rename menuentries (they stey updatable by update-grub)
- edit the contents of menuentries or create new ones (internally it edits the 40_custom)
- support for GRUB2 and BURG
- reinstallation of the bootloader to MBR
- settings like default operating system, kernel params, background image and text colors etc.
- changing the installed operating system by running on a live cd

References:

[Launchpad Project Link](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)