# How do I install super boot manager?

Tags: grub2

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 and I am unable to install super boot manager? Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: Thanks. Works on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and Linux Mint 17 x64 Cinnamon. Can't upvote because of reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install `super-boot-manager` on Ubuntu 14.04, run the below commands on terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ingalex-super-boot-manager-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install super-boot-manager
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Finally run it by,

```
super-boot-manager
```

Comment: How do i accept your answer is there something I need to do? I am new to this site...

Comment: Enable the tick mark below the down arrow in my answer.