# BURG For Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: apt, ppa, burg

As the title.. how do i do that?
i really want that.. but ingalex has removed the folder..
making `sudo apt-get update` show a error like this

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burg for Ubuntu 14.04 is available at `ppa:n-muench/burg` PPA. Run the below commands on terminal to install Burg on Ubuntu 14.04 from muench PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg
```

This below error report clearly shows that the PPA owner didn't updated his PPA for trusty to provide `super-boot-manager` package. So please wait for his updation.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

If you want to remove the above NOT FOUND PPA then run the below command on terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
```

Comment: and i also need super boot manager

Comment: then follow this http://askubuntu.com/a/449828/202806 answer.

Comment: one last thing.. i didn't press space at the end of configuring burg.. any ways to redo all agaibn?

Comment: try space or tab to select the options.

Comment: i didn't press space.. just entered it..

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier poster said, you have to use the PPA `ppa:n-muench/burg` .
As for installing super-boot-manager on 14.04, it is still at the time of writing not updated in the ppa for 14.04. I followed the guide in [THIS TUTORIAL](http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/other/bootstrap-datepicker.html) to bypass that. Use:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
    sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ingalex-super-boot-manager-trusty.list"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install super-boot-manager
    sudo apt-get install -f
```

The Tut where i found this: http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html