# Grub theme file location

Tags: grub2

Where should I place a grub theme file?
I read grub manual and didn't find anything about exact folder to place it in.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use grub customizer?

To install it use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm ages late, but:

```
/boot/grub/themes
```

Then you should edit it in grub customizer