# GRUB doesn't show Windows loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

[Windows loading screen](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nCbGMesEAa0/maxresdefault.jpg)

This is a normal windows loading screen right after we select the option from GRUB right?

However, my loading screen when I select to windows open **appears** the circle running and I cannot see any of windows 10 logo [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMvN9.jpg) above.

My laptop is the new AERO 15W i7 8750H GTX 1060 and it has a built-in GIGABYTE windows bootloader screen

Comment: I actually like the way only the spinning circle appears and wish there was a way of making all the other options like Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 work the same way on my grub menu. You could explore setting up a grub background image to make it less boring: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub

Comment: Thank you. It was able to bring to the normal windows booting screen (in my case the windows is replaced with GIGABYTE) by pressing `F9` then choose to boot back to GRUB. Anyway, i think that should be a software problems as GIGABYTE doesn't publish any of the keyboard drivers for Linux in general (to my understanding because they said to me that they don't officially support Linux drivers and encourage users to use Windows instead)